# PhoneGap explanation

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have an existing web application that is used by my coworkers. This web application uses pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I am only communicating via the back-end with web services. I would like to leverage native functionality where possible. I've stumbled upon PhoneGap. From what I can tell there is basically a JavaScript file called phonegap-[version].js. From my understanding, this file is a basically a wrapper API. Then, you can push your code out to the various marketplaces by using the Getting Started information (http://phonegap.com/start#wp).

My question is about the phonegap-[version].js file. Currently, my application works fine over the mobile web. Is there a way to detect if phonegap is an option? Or detect if my code is running natively? For instance, I want to pass the device info back to a service. For that, I decided to use:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.platform. My impression was, if the application was running in the browser, phonegap would automatically use navigator.useragent. But, if it was running on a native device, it would use the compiled rendition and pass more specific information.

Am I making sense? Do I have a misunderstanding? I guess my impression was, I would use phonegap-[version].js and it would use device features if it was running as a native app. Otherwise, there would be hooks to fail gracefully. Can someone please steer me straight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its more than this Phone gap is an objective-c library for deploying html5 files through XCode to the apple app store. All files should live on the device as html files, and make ajax calls to web services and then parse that data into html5 views. Phone gap also allows you to use native apis via it's objective-c bridge, such as Camera, FileSystem, CoreGraphics, CoreData, etc.

In short you wouldn't use phonegap-version.js on a mobile website, you would use it if you were packaging an html5 application as a native app for an Appstore and want to leverage a devices native apis from javascript?

You wouldn't need to detect it as your would need to deploy 2 slighty different code bases, one for the mobile web and one for running in an app container. You could add a variable to your device branch that says

```
var runningOnDevice = true;
```

and one for your mobile web that says

```
var runningOnDevice = false;
```

Am I Making Sense?